# How to attach a local CSS file to a website?

Tags: windows-xp, website, webserver

I want to keep a CSS file in my PC but want to link that file in website and whatever changes I will do in local file that changes should reflect in site.

I'm not logged in as Admin in my PC. Is it possible?

I need any online/offline method Compatible with Windows XP 32 bit

Comment: There are various browser-specific options (e.g. I used to do this often in Opera), but you've not mentioned a browser.

Comment: yes tell me i've mentioned any offline/online method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check out the Stylish extension for mozilla firefox. Not exactly what you're looking for, but it allows you to overwrite CSS for arbitrary websites (or firefox's chrome, if you like)